# Xcode 9 Apple TV4 Connect via network

Tags: xcode, xcode9, remote-debugging, tvos

I tried to remotely debug an App running on Apple TV4 (tvOS11) from Xcode 9 but I'm facing an issue as I'm not able to activate the "Connect via network" as this option still greyed/disabled in Xcode 9.

I checked if something was wrong in the AppleTV settings without any success. Sure, that my MacBook is on the same network:

MacBook IP 192.168.0.23
Apple TV IP: 192.168.0.39

Of course Apple TV appears in Xcode when connected with the USB link.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone have some ideas ?

Answer (score 12):

My suggestion would be to do below steps in order.

**Note** that if there is network issue, then below steps might not work for you.

1. First, Unpair your apple TV from your MacBook.
2. Go to Settings>Remotes and Devices>Remote App and Devices on your Apple TV.
3. Now open Xcode Devices and Simulators Window, you will see Apple TV appearing in the Discovered list in the left section.
4. Click on Apple TV Icon in Devices panel, it will ask you for Pairing Code.
5. Enter the pairing code, and Xcode should start pairing with the Apple TV.

Now, you should see connect to network option enabled. 
Let me know if that works for you. Cheers!